# How to create execute function a one time using wp-cron

Tags: wordpress, plugins

I create a plugin for send woocommerce data external system plugin i want create a cron run a one time like only run after plugin active success
this is i'm used cron code

```
 add_action('wpse71941_cron', 'wpse71941_long_running');
function wpse71941_long_running($args)
{
    
    // might need to call `set_time_limit` here
    set_time_limit(0);

    include 'customers.php';
        include 'orders.php';
        include 'products.php';

    // return normal time limit
    if($l = ini_get('max_execution_time'))
        set_time_limit($l);
}

// schedule the event for right now
wp_schedule_single_event(
    time(), 
    'wpse71941_cron', 
    array('args' => 'for', 'callback' => 'function')
);
```

any suggestions to send data in background process using corn or any?